# Typoscript: Wrap Content element

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I would like to display content of subsites and wrap them in specific divs. Here is my code:

```
lib.content = CONTENT
lib.content {
  stdWrap.wrap = <div id="sub-content-scroll">|</div>
  renderObj.stdWrap.wrap = <div class="page">|</div>
  table = tt_content
  select {
    pidInList.cObject < lib.allPid
    where = colPos = 0
    orderBy = pid
  }    
}
```

My question is: How can I wrap the  only per pid. Now it wraps all content element with the page div. But I want to achieve the wrap by site. PS: lib.allPid is a kommaseparated list with ids.

Can someone help me?

Thank you very much
Coreblade

Comment: You can use `Section Frame` for this: http://typo3.org/documentation/snippets/sd/38/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer

I solved my Problem. The solution was to implement both (lib.content and lib.allPid) in one:

```
lib.content = HMENU
lib.content {
  stdWrap.wrap = <div id="sub-content-scroll">|</div>
  special = directory
  special.value = 7
  1 = TMENU
  1.NO {
    doNotLinkIt = 1
    field = uid
    stdWrap.cObject = CONTENT
    stdWrap.cObject {
      wrap = <div class="page">|</div>
      table = tt_content
      select {
        pidInList.field = uid
        where = colPos = 0
        orderBy = pid
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ragards Coreblade